# meaning of "all got in on the fun"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> At last the play began again, but the
>   audience had lost interest. One man shouted,
>   “People of Paris! This play is not amusing.
>   Nothing happens! I thought we were going to
>   select the Pope of Fools. In my city of Ghent,
>   this is how we do it: A crowd such as this one
>   gathers. Then anyone who chooses puts his
>   head through a hole and makes an ugly face.
>   The one who makes the ugliest face is chosen
>   Pope. That’s it! It’s a lot of fun, I tell you.
>   Shall we choose your Pope of Fools this way?
>   It will surely be more amusing than watching
>   any more of this boring play.”
>   The audience clapped in agreement.
>   Someone broke the glass out of a small round
>   window. Then people started putting their
>   heads through the empty circle of stone.
>   Every human expression was seen. Men and
>   women, young and old, scholars and
>   shopkeepers—**all got in on the fun**.

Dose it mean all people enjoyed seeing those funny expression?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. All people joined in the fun. See **[get in on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_in_on)**

Comment: Thank you so much , yes I see but I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

"Got in on" means participated in, or enjoyed the benefit of. You could say, "I got in on the stock market boom" or "Sally threw a big party and Bob got in on it."

"The fun" here may mean specifically the entertainment value of people making funny faces, or more generally of the play as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

"Got in on" means "participated in".

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.